# Como fazer uma quebra de texto no Excel programaticamente com uma verificação em C #

Tags: c#, microsoft-excel, quebras-de-linha

Eu estou usando os `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` para criar um relatório do Excel a partir de um arquivo txt.

Tudo funciona perfeito, mas, as vezes, algumas colunas tornam-se extremamente grandes e quando precisamos de imprimir, é necessário redimensionar e fica horrível

Quando eu tento quebra-la usando o `Range.Style.WrapText = true`, fica estranho, assim:

[image: Minha maneira]

Estou pensando em uma maneira de quebrar as frases que têm mais de 20 caracteres. e obter algo assim:

[image: A maneira que meu chefe quer]

o pior é que, no excel, quando clico no texto (como eu deveria fazer quando vou editá-lo) ele fica da maneira que eu queria.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

aqui meu código.

```
    //ignorem o loop, ele é para pegar o texto exato vindo do txt
    for (int x = 0; x < text.Length - 2; x++)
    {
            if(text[x].Length > 20)
            {
                //fazer a quebra...mas como?
                app.Cells[i,j] =  text[x + 1].Trim();
            }
            else
            {
                app.Cells[i,j] =  text[x + 1].Trim();
            }
    }
    //Range usado para a formatação.
    Range formatPaiP1 = app.get_Range(letraColunaP1, BuscarAlfabeto(9) + (i).ToString());
    formatPaiP1.WrapText = true;
    formatPaiP1.EntireRow.AutoFit();
    formatPaiP1.VerticalAlignment = Constants.xlCenter;
    formatPaiP1.EntireColumn.AutoFit();
    formatPaiP1.Font.Bold = true;
    formatPaiP1.Font.Name = "Arial";
    formatPaiP1.Font.Size = 12;
```

Comment: O negócio é ir com `Range.Style.WrapText = true` mesmo. Tá "estranho" porque ficou ocupando o espaço de 3 linhas ao invés de duas? Redimensione a coluna oras. Deixe mais larga pra ocupar apenas duas linhas.

Comment: As colunas também estão com `formatPaiP1.EntireColumn.AutoFit();`

Comment: No Excel para usar quebra de linha você tem que pressionar Alt + Enter, já tentou colocar esses dois caracteres no final do texto? Não coloquei como resposta pois não tenho o Visual Studio aqui para testar, se der certo avise que crio como resposta!

Comment: @GuilhermeGolfetto já tentou mudar o formato do arquivo de txt para csv?

Comment: @GuilhermeGolfetto Já tentou adicionar "\r\n" na string?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solucionei o problema com a ajuda do @rodorgas de uma maneira "alternativa" (leia:adequação a nível técnico). Fiz a seguinte alteração:

```
formatPaiP1.WrapText = true;
formatPaiP1.EntireRow.RowHeight = 33;
```

notei que ao usar o WrapText a linha ficava com 66 de altura, quebrando ela ao meio, o excel a ajusta corretamente em todos os meus casos.

Essa é uma solução que funcionou exclusivamente para o meu projeto. Imagino que tem tiver o mesmo problema talvez não possa adotar a mesma "lógica".

Resultado:

[image: Resultado]

Obrigado a todos pela ajuda.